# CSS Visibility on Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, visibility

I wanted to try making custom radio buttons, however they only work on Chrome and Opera.

On Edge what I create using ::after is invisible, however on other browsers it is visible.

The problem seems to be visibility: hidden on radio. On Edge its children disappear, but on other Browsers visiblility:visible brings them back.

```css
[type=radio] {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  visibility: visible;
}

[type=radio]::after {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  background-color: pink;
  visibility: visible;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio">
```

Comment: input are not supposed to generate pseudo elements, Your code does not reproduce your issue. Can you clarify ?

Comment: @G-Cyr  Running the code snippet on Opera/Chrome works. On Edge (I tested my version and an emulator) it produces the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radio button in your code snippet doesn't change when clicked in Chrome. I made a demo in which the radio button's `background-color` will change to pink when clicked. I test it in Edge and Chrome and it works. You could check the code below.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio01" name="radio" />
<label for="radio01"><span></span></label>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tested it out and it works. I really appreciate your help :-)